# EntityState.Modified without updating navigation property

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

i'm having trouble updating one of my models using EntityState.Modified, as it also tries to update my navigation property (which i am not changing). My controller action is:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Rooms([Bind(Include = "ID,BedroomCount,BedroomsDescription,BathroomCount,BathroomsDescription")] Property property)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Modify property
            property.DateModified = DateTime.Now;
            property.Status = 1;
            db.Entry(property).State = EntityState.Modified;
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(property);
    }
```

And my model looks like:

```
public class Property
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public Int16 BedroomCount { get; set; }

    public string BedroomsDescription { get; set; }

    public Int16 BathroomCount { get; set; }

    public string BathroomsDescription { get; set; }

    public int CommunityID { get; set; }

    public int PropertyTypeID { get; set; }

    public virtual Community Community { get; set; }
    public virtual PropertyType PropertyType { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, i binding a bunch of stuff (bathroom and bedroom counts etc) from my viewModel, but i am not modifying the navigation property 'Community' at all, but whenever i post to this action method, i get the following error:

> The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_dbo.Property_dbo.Community_CommunityID". The conflict occurred in
>   database "MyDatabase", table "dbo.Community", column 'ID'. The
>   statement has been terminated.

How can i update this model without it trying to update the foreign key? I can't find the answer anywhere

Comment: I am also facing this issue right now, I resolved it using property.Community = null. I know its not the permanent fix but I couldn't find an answer too

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I don't want my community as null. Now I *can* pass it too and from my viewmodel, but it seems really unnecessary since I don't need to change it

Comment: Yeah in my case, I was updating my entity from my data access specific for that entity so I could afford knowing a call to update child can't come there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi can you please give a try I hope it will work .

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Rooms([Bind(Include = "ID,BedroomCount,BedroomsDescription,BathroomCount,BathroomsDescription")] Property property)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // try this read this entoity from context and update properties you need to update
       var dbproperty = db.Property.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id= property.Id); // handle null 
        //Modify property
        dbproperty .DateModified = DateTime.Now;
        dbproperty .Status = 1;      

       // assuming in your context class Properties is the name of table.
         db.Entry(dbproperty ).State = EntityState.Modified;
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(property);
}
```

Comment: The code above looks like it's trying to create a new entry in the database, but i want to modify an existing entry?

Comment: Please try let me know if you have any issues . I am assuming that this row is present alrady otherwise we can handle null case for FirstOrDefault as I commented  in answer

Comment: This "db.properties.Add(dbproperty )" clearly says it is trying to add the property to context and would through an exception "Entity with same already exists" I believe

Comment: @AliBaig thanks for pointing out I updated my answer and check it is now updating the current record . Also I checked no updates for Child properties as there is no change .

Comment: @Gavin5511 Sorry I missed that part I checked now and updated answer .

Comment: I'm not getting the error anymore, but it isn't updating. Do i need to change the binding from 'Property property' (data model) to use my viewmodel instead?

Comment: @Gavin5511 : That good news : And yes you need to update the EF model class properties I missed that part so can you try to update any property of Property Entity which is your DbContext class lest say BathroomsDescription  ="test" . Just to confirm if it works .

Comment: @Gavin5511 I tested with my EF Entity class and it worked for me . I hope it works for you .

Answer (score 0):

Set the state of the nav property also to `EntityState.Unchanged` or `EntityState.Modified`.

Or, set the nav property to null before `db.Entry(property).State = EntityState.Modified;`.